# VSFTPD 553 error: could not create file

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2, vsftpd

Fresh LAMP server setup with Ubuntu 12.04 and VSFTPD.

I'm trying to access the `/var/www` folder (web root) with FTP user.

I created a new user `ftpuser` and added it to the `www-data` user group created automatically by Apache.
Home directory of that user is set to `/var/www`.
I also changed the ownership of the `/var/www` to `www-data` group and changed permissions to `02775`.

However, I'm still not able to upload files. Error is: "553 Could not create file".

1. Can someone please explain me how to set these permissions properly?
2. What is the correct setup? Should I set the home directory of `ftpuser` to `/var/www` or somehow diffeerently?

I found a lot of topics on the web but none of them offer a universal solution.

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the output of `ls -l` of `/var/www`:

`drwxr-sr-x 3 root ftpuser 4096`

Content of `vsftpd.conf` file:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=ftpuser
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find out anything?

Comment: Unfortunately no - I gave up and started using git for pushing the code for all projects on that server. It is a dev/testing server only..

Comment: After some time, I ended up in the same situation on a new server, and Amin Y's answer was the right thing. Permissions were wrong and forcing them again on the folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is because your folder is owned by `root`, instead of `ftpuser`.

To fix it run:

```
sudo chown -R ftpuser:nogroup /var/www/ftuuserfolder
```

Answer (score 2):

I found I had set the correct ownership, but not the correct permissions.

---

If your folder is owned by the user 'ftpuser' and group 'www-data' for example, like...

`drwxr-sr-x 3 ftpuser www-data 4096`

Then you probably haven't run...

`sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/ftpuserfolder`

Which gives write permission to the group that owns those files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

For me nothing worked. I figured out that the **initial directory** in my FTP Client was set to nothing, so it tried to access the linux root directory. I was letting it empty first, because I thought it will pick the users home directory.

I had to specify the full path to the project.