# FTP account for just one directory

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd

**Background information:**

I'm using Serverpilot to manage my Ubuntu server which doesn't provide any FTP service.

- There is a user: `serverpilot`
- With the home directory: `/srv/users/serverpilot/`
- And there is a website running in this directory: `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/website/public/`.

**What I want:**

Now I would like to have a FTP account which can only read and write to this directory: `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/website/public/ftpdir/`.

**What I've tried:**

- I've installed vsftpd: `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`
- Created a new user with that directory as home: `sudo useradd -m -d /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/website/public/ftpdir ftpuser` (wich is probably not a good idea to have a home directory of a user in another users home directory)
- I've changed the password with `sudo passwd ftpuser`
- Edited the default vsftpd configuration with `sudo vi /etc/vsftpd.conf`

  - `local_enable=YES` so the `ftpuser` can be used as ftp login
  - `write_enable=YES` the user is able to write
  - `chroot_local_user=YES` can't access anything outside it's home dir
  - `pam_service_name=ftp` because I was getting a [530 Login incorrect error](https://askubuntu.com/a/413694)
- And opened my firewall with: `sudo ufw allow 21/tcp`

**The problems:**

- Other users beside the `ftpuser` can also be used as FTP login. I just want to have 1 ftp user and not allow other system users to use FTP.
- The `ftpuser` can also SSH into the server.
- I'm getting a `553 error: could not create file` error when trying to upload a file, to fix this I came across this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/320186 but I don't think this is the right way because the file should be owned by the `serverpilot` user, not the `ftpuser` user. The website running under the `serverpilot` user should proces the uploaded files.

**How I've solved it before:**

In the past on another server I've changed the directory ownership and after adding these extra vsftpd configuration options it was finally working:

```
file_open_mode=0775
local_umask=022
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

But on that server I had problems with processing the uploaded files because of the ownership, so there I'm using the `file_get_contents()` PHP function to get the files over the web instead of direct access them on the server which isn't that nice.

**The final question:**

How can I simply have 1 ftp login which can read and write to a directory in a users home directory where the ownership stays on the user where the home directory is from?

Comment: Does it have to be FTP? Won't SFTP do?

Comment: SFTP won't do, it's for a external service which one support FTP to upload certain files to my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local_enable=YES is what is enabling the other users to login, you should add your user to the explict user list instead

from the manual:

```
local_enable
Controls whether local logins are permitted or not. If enabled,       normal user accounts in /etc/passwd (or wherever your PAM config references) may be used to log in. This must be enable for any non-anonymous login to work, including virtual users.
Default: NO

userlist_file
This option is the name of the file loaded when the userlist_enable option is active.
Default: /etc/vsftpd.user_list
```

To sort your permissions issues enable the SITE CHMOD command and get your ftp client to use it

```
chmod_enable
When enabled, allows use of the SITE CHMOD command. NOTE! This only applies to local users. Anonymous users never get to use SITE CHMOD.
Default: YES
```

Answer (score 4):

`vsftpd` doesn't support limit users but `proftpd` is more powerfull and has an option in configuration file (`proftpd.conf`) to limit login to some user like this:

```
<Limit LOGIN>
AllowUser barb
AllowUser dave
AllowGroup ftpuser
DenyAll
</Limit>
```

**Edit**

1. for your first problem the solution is as above.
2. second problem also can solve by adding `DenyUsers    ftpuser` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
3. and third problem can solve by adding `ftpuser` to the group of `serverpilot` and add `serverpilot` to the group of `ftpuser`. also you must change permission of folder `/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/website/public/ftpdir` to 775.

Remember that folder `/srv/users/serverpilot/` must have 755 permission.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it's not answering my other questions/problems, any thoughts on that?

Comment: for read/write problem you can change group permission of user home directory to `rwx` and add your ftp user to the group of user whom the home directory is from.

Comment: And what about the users home directory? Is it okay to have a users home directory inside another users home directory? Is there not a FTP solution with FTP logins separated from the system users? Just install, create a FTP login and define it's directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pure-ftpd` 's `PureDB` function to create a ftp login only for the `pure-ftpd` service.